# Count Distinct is counting all instances

Tags: sql, metabase

Hi I have a field called `Document.id` I am trying to count distinct occurrences of this by grouping another field. It is counting all occurrences against the all the group.

| Document.id | Orgdoctype.id |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1234 |
| 6 | 7876 |

```sql
SELECT `OrderDocumentType`.`orderId` AS `orderId`
    , `OrderDocumentType`.`status` AS `status`
    , `Orgdocumenttype`.`name` AS `Orgdocumenttype__name`
    , `Orgdocumenttype`.`needsApproval` AS `Orgdocumenttype__needsApproval`
    , `Order`.`status` AS `Order__status`
    , Group_concat(`Annotation`.`text`) AS `Annotation__text`
    , Count (distinct `Document`.`id`)
    , `Orgdocumenttype`.`id` 
FROM `OrderDocumentType`
    LEFT JOIN `OrgDocumentType` AS `Orgdocumenttype` ON `OrderDocumentType`.`orgDocumentTypeId` = `Orgdocumenttype`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `Order` AS `Order` ON `OrderDocumentType`.`orderId` = `Order`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `Document` AS `Document` ON `Orgdocumenttype`.`id`= `Document`.`orgDocumentTypeId` 
    LEFT JOIN `DocumentImage` AS `Documentimage` ON `Document`.`id` = `Documentimage`.`documentId` 
    LEFT JOIN `Annotation` AS `Annotation` ON `Documentimage`.`id` = `Annotation`.`documentImageId`
WHERE `OrderDocumentType`.`orgId` = 2556
    AND (`Order`.`status` <> 'CANCELLED_BY_HAVEN' OR `Order`.`status` IS NULL)
    AND (`Order`.`status` <> 'CANCELLATION_REQUESTED_BY_SHIPPER' OR `Order`.`status` IS NULL) 
    AND (`Order`.`status` <> 'CANCELLED_BY_PROVIDER' OR `Order`.`status` IS NULL) 
    AND (`Order`.`status` <> 'CANCELLED_BY_SHIPPER' OR `Order`.`status` IS NULL) 
    AND (`Order`.`status` <> 'EXPIRED' OR `Order`.`status` IS NULL) 
    AND `Orgdocumenttype`.`needsApproval` = TRUE 
    AND `OrderDocumentType`.`orderId` = 474019
GROUP BY `Orgdocumenttype`.`id`
```

I have tried different `GROUP BY`'s but it then shows all rows.

Sorry here is update I can't attach but above is the current code and below tables show what is happening and also what should happen.

I used below code to get what should happen

```sql
SELECT `Document`.`orgDocumentTypeId` AS `orgDocumentTypeId`
    , `Orgdocumenttype`.`name` AS `Orgdocumenttype__name`
    , Count (distinct `Document`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `Document`
    LEFT JOIN `OrgDocumentType` AS `Orgdocumenttype` ON `Document`.`OrgdocumentTypeId` = `Orgdocumenttype`.`id`
WHERE `Document`.`orderId` = 474019
GROUP BY `Document`.`orgDocumentTypeId`
    , `Orgdocumenttype`.`name`
ORDER BY `Document`.`orgDocumentTypeId` ASC
    , `Orgdocumenttype`.`name` ASC
```

current

| Orgdoctype__name | Count `Document`.`id` | orgDocTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill of Lading | 10 | 2720 |
| PL-Packing List | 6 | 2841 |
| Certificate of Origin | 8 | 2863 |
| Commercial Invoice | 6 | 2864 |

What I get with the other code and what I need

| Orgdoctype__name | Count `Document`.`id` | orgDocTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill of Lading | 3 | 2720 |
| PL-Packing List | 3 | 2841 |
| Certificate of Origin | 1 | 2863 |
| Commercial Invoice | 2 | 2864 |
| Booking Confirmation | 1 | 2742 |

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, both initial data and expected results, to demonstrate both what you are getting and what you actually want. Ideally a simplified example. [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: sorry new to this do I need to add anything else?